# DropDown Content is not working (MVC)

Tags: jquery, css, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on my **MVCOnlineShop** Project. I'm trying to make a drop down list, Categories as the `dropdown` button and products as the `drop down content` , I got the categories working , but no `drop down content`.I think it's all about the html tags.

and i made a `partial view` called `CategoryLayout.cshtml`:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CategoryLayout";
}

@foreach (var Category in Model)
{
   <li>
       <div class="dropdown">
           <button class="dropbtn">@Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName,
"ProductList", new { Category = Category.CategoryID })</button>
       </div>
   </li>

   <div class="dropdown-content">
       @foreach (var Product in Category.Products)
       {
           <li>@Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName,
"Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID })</li>
       }
    </div>
}
```

and this is what i wrote in `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @Html.Partial("CategoryLayout")
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Can you help me please, I'm stuck. Am I missing something ?

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: I don't see any dropdown control in your code. Or maybe i'm not seeing right?

Comment: @Ahmad: can you include the controller logic in the question please

Comment: @Ahmad those are not dropdowns, they're ActionLinks (used as menu tags) as the image you posted clearly shows as well

Comment: this is the code <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn"> to the drop down , and the drop down content below it , but how to make it work @ADyson

Comment: yeah on this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover , and trying to add my code of the categories and products , my codes are working fine @ADyson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having now edit your code to be actually readable, I can see you aren't producing the same layout in your View as in the howto you mentioned at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover.

The basic structure shown there is:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comparing this with your code, I think your closing `</li>` needs to come *after* the end of the div which has the class "dropdown-content", and the "dropdown-content" div needs to be within the "dropdown" div. the "dropdown-content" should not include another `<li>`. `<li>` should only be a child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`, apart from anything else, plus I'm sure it's breaking the CSS which describes the dropdown effect. Lastly your Layout page has an orphan `</div>` at the end.

This should be more like it:

CategoryLayout.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCOnlineShop.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CategoryLayout";
}

@foreach (var Category in Model)
{
   <li>
       <div class="dropdown">
           <button class="dropbtn">@Html.ActionLink(Category.CategoryName,
"ProductList", new { Category = Category.CategoryID })</button>

           <div class="dropdown-content">
               @foreach (var Product in Category.Products)
               {
                   @Html.ActionLink(Product.ProductName,
"Details", new { id = Product.CategoryID })
               }
           </div>
       </div>
   </li>
}
```

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        @Html.Partial("CategoryLayout")
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you're not sure why I've changed what I have , I suggest you study the how-to's HTML markup a little more closely. As a debugging tool you can also use the "View Source" feature of your browser to compare what your code's final output looks like, vs what's in the how-to. Sometimes with Razor syntax in there, and loops etc it can be hard to visualise the final result. Also, your erratic formatting and indentation was making it unclear too.

Comment: this was really a helpful answer , i will learn about the HTML markup, because yeah i was getting that li can't be nested inside div , thank you so muchhh!!